# Бесконечный редирект Wordpress при использовании ssl (https)

Tags: wordpress, редирект, https, ssl

При указании https протокола в адресной строке, Wordpress впадает в бесконечный цикл редиректов. Не могу выявить проблему. Пробовал отключать все плагины и менять темы. Ни чего не помогает. Админка https работает нормально, а сайт не грузится.

вот мой .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Так же пробовал выставлять в панели администрирования Адрес WordPress (URL) и Адрес сайта (URL) с https, то же не помогает. Обновлял постоянные ссылки, тоже ни чего.

Версия WP 4.3

Comment: У вас связка nginx + apache?

Comment: возможно у Вас файлы для http и https находятся в различный папках, (может сервер так настроен) и оба редиректится друг на друга.

Comment: Да у меня связка nginx + apache. Где можно посмотреть настройки сервера которые влияют на данный редирект?

Comment: Покажите конфиги виртуальных хостов Apache и nginx. Прямо в сообщении, воспользовавшись функцией редактирования.

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в `.htaccess` строчку:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

А в `wp-config.php`:

```
const FORCE_SSL_ADMIN = true;
```

Comment: Думаешь за 1,5 года проблема не решилась? ;)

Comment: @SeVlad решение может понадобиться другим.

Comment: Каким образом Вы диагностировали проблему? Почему она возникает и почему Ваше решение её побеждает? Можно более ёмко ответить на вопрос? Никто не сможет его уже оценить по истечении такого времени без подробных объяснений.

Comment: Не рабочее решенее